# How are the dot products defined between two vectors in the Poincaré Ball Model of the Hyperbolic Geometry

Tags: geometry, inner-products, hyperbolic-geometry

I am trying to gain more insight about the hyperbolic spaces, and in particular the Poincaré ball model. I got the basic intuition between the idea and how basic computations such as distances and the metrics can be defined in the Poincaré ball model. However, some aspects of the idea are still a mystery for me.

Assume that we have two points on a $d$-dimensional Poincaré ball; i.e., $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Both $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ have norms less than one. What I would like to know is: "how is the dot product between these two points defined in the Poincaré ball model?"

Comment: Why not try starting with the polarization identity?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @J.M.isnotamathematician, but what do you exactly mean? Do you mean for instance to use $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}=||\mathbf{x}||||\mathbf{y}||cos(θ)$ to derive the inner product? Wouldn't this identity hold only in Euclidean space?

Comment: That's the definition of the (Euclidean) dot product, not the polarization identity. Did you look it up like I told you to?

Comment: Yep, I have checked the wikipedia def'n (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), but still I am not sure how to derive the dot product using the polarization identity. BTW, I have found a definition of the distance in the hyperbolic space from which deriving the dot product becomes trivial on the Poincare Ball.

Comment: @mathamania What definition did you find?